# recv() only gets 1460 bytes from loopback on Windows 8

Tags: windows, sockets, ipc

I'm using loopback for IPC and data packets are mostly over 4KB. I found that if I send() frequently using two threads(which share the same socket) from a client, sometimes the server only receive 1460(seems to be the MTU of Ethernet?) bytes with a single recv(). What's the reason? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using datagrams (UDP) or a stream (TCP)? If a stream, then there's no guarantee that receives will occur on the same message boundaries as the sends.  You'll get the remaining data in subsequent calls to `recv()`. If message boundaries are important to you, then you'll need to encode them in your messages somehow (like with a header that indicates the message length or with delimiters of some sort).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Hi. I'm using TCP. I somehow used to believe there is no fragmentation in loopback communication... Now this seems to be wrong. So I add a size field in the packet to check integrity:).

Comment: You don't need a size field. You just need to pay attentionto the count value returned by `recv().`